# vertical rolling background image with static navigation

Tags: static, navigation

Allright so i'm a little new to web development and i'm trying to make a site.  What i'm trying to do is have a really large background image which has multiple sections in the image, they are all marked with different colors, and I want to add a nav bar so that everytime that you click a link in the nav, the nav bar stays however, the background image moves up to the next section.  I tried coding use section id="" but that didn't really work.  I also tried incorporating jquery but had little effect with that.

Can someone please help. i've been at this for awhile.

Thanks
Riz

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use hash tags but you would have to (and in fact - **should**) split you background image into multiple pieces.

Resulting CSS should look something like this:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}

#nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
}

    #nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
            padding: 0;
        }

#section1 {
    background: #ff0000 url(/path/to/background1.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    height: 400px; /* change to whatever it needs to be */
}

#section2 {
    background: #00ff00 url(/path/to/background2.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    height: 400px; /* change to whatever it needs to be */
}

#section3 {
    background: #0000ff url(/path/to/background3.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    height: 400px; /* change to whatever it needs to be */
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">first section</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">second section</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">third section</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="section1"> ... </div>
<div id="section2"> ... </div>
<div id="section3"> ... </div>
```

Comment: this definitely helps a lot.  I will try this out however the image i have is curved at the different sections.  The company wants just one single image and it has to have a smooth transition. i will try this out though.

Comment: the other thing is that the background-image has to slide up. do you think jquery .slideUp() or .toggle() will have a nice effect.  I looked at both the libraries and I found something that might work however it just shows/hides the content, it doesn't actually slide the content up.

Comment: See if this will be any help: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: Alternatively, you can always attach your background image to the <body> and still use div's with specific heights.